# Mac Software Updates and App Store don't work over Google Nest wi-fi

Tags: mac, wifi, google

Not actually sure if this is a Google issue or an Apple issue, but appreciate any insight. My Mac won't load the App Store (the window stays white with no content) and won't download MacOS software updates over my Google Nest wi-fi network.

As soon as I tether my computer to my phone, the App Store loads, or the software updates begin, so the issue definitely seems to be related to the network.

The network is a Google Nest wi-fi mesh network. There is one base station and two bridged stations. The reliability is good for everything else—web browsing, Netflix, even iOS updates on my phone—but doesn't seem to allow the App Store or Software Updates to load.

All I can guess at is that my network might be blocking one of the ports that Apple relies upon for performing updates or loading the app store. I found this page which lists all of the ports and servers necessary for MacOS to do its thing: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT210060

In the Google Home app, in the Settings page, there is a "Port Management" section, which allows me to configure elements of the network: set up parental filters, notifications of outages etc, there is an "Advanced Networking" sections which includes an area for Port Management. This does not indicate that any ports are being blocked. It looks like you can add port forwarding rules, but I haven't played with this (https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/6274503#how&zippy=%2Cnat-loopback%2Cwith-the-google-wifi-app%2Cwith-the-google-home-app)

Appreciate any suggestions for how to fix this, as regularly tethering to my phone is wearing thin. If port forwarding is necessary, what settings would I use to permit the App Store or Software Updates to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that the fix for this was to change the Network Location (**System Preferences** > **Network** > **Location**). Mine was set to Automatic, so I created a new location called "Home" and used that.

Even though the Wi-Fi network I was connecting to was the same, this act of changing the location made all the difference and I can now happily perform software updates, load and interact with the App Store, and generally use my network connection for everything I need to use it for.